# Will Google Identity Service migration impact the authorization URL?

Tags: google-signin, google-identity

As a developer using Google API, I received the email "Migrate to the new Google Identity Services library". Our application has both Web-based and client solutions. We use Google Sign-In JavaScript library in the Web-based solution, which needs to be migrated. Our client solution calls the `GetAuthorizationUrl()` method of `OAuth2ProviderForApplications` in Google API .NET library to get the authorization URL and launch a browser window with the URL.

Is the URL from the .NET library affected by this migration?

I compared the URLs in the windows launched by both Google Sign-In and GIS and those from the .NET library. There seemed to be some difference:

1. GIS:
   https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth/oauthchooseaccount?...
2. Google Sign-in Javascript:
   https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth/oauthchooseaccount?...
3. Google API .NET library:
   https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?...

#2 and #3 are currently used in our system. When upgraded from Google Sign-in (#2) to GIS (#1), the authorization URL has "v2".

Is the "non v2" version of the authorization URL endpoint (#3) still valid after migration? As we will keep getting this non-v2 URL from the .NET library, it is important to make sure it is still working to avoid our service interruption.